# WPF MMV pattern.send active property to another Viewodel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to develop a WPF program with MVVM pattern. I have created 2 view models.

- The first viewmodel: display a list of airports. Each airport is clickable.
- The second viewmodel: is used to display detail information on the airport clicked.

My problem is that i' am not able to pass the active click airport to viewmodel2. After some research, I think I have to use a  mediator pattern to  communicate between the 2 view models, but I really don' t understand how to implement it.

It will be very nice if you could help me in coding.

You will find and extract of my code.

VIEWMODEL1:

```
    public AirportViewModel()
    {
        Airports = new ObservableCollection<AirportModel>(GetData.GetAirportData());//LOAD AIRPORTS FROM XML FILE
        GetAirportIdCommand = new RelayCommand(GetAirportIdExecute, GetAirportIdCanExeucte);
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<AirportModel> Airports { get; set; }

    private AirportModel selectAirport; // AIRPORT CLICK AND NEED TO BE SEND To VIEWMODEL2

    public AirportModel SelectAirport
    {
        get { return selectAirport; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectAirport)
            { 
                selectAirport = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectAirport");
            }
         }
    }

    public RelayCommand GetAirportIdCommand { get; set; }

    public void GetAirportIdExecute(object parameter)   // COMMAND TO SELECT AN AIRPORT
    {          
        int IdSelectAirport = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        SelectAirport = Airports[IdSelectAirport];
        AirportDataWindowViewModel.AirportDataWindowModel.WidthNotam = 500;
    }

    public bool GetAirportIdCanExeucte(object parameter)
    {
        //Bouton toujours actif
        return true;
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
```

VIEWMODEL 2

get the clicked airport

Hope you can help!

Thanks in advance

cyrille

Comment: How many views do you have? If you have one, you can contain everything in one viewmodel and skip all the unnecessary work in having to deal with multiple viewmodels.

Comment: I expect minimum 4 views for this project. Like you say i could deal with 1 viewmodel. But i prefere to separate the code with element to display. All what i need is to be able to get the property SelectAirport  within the other viewmodel

Comment: You could use an event aggregator to send "events" between view models in a loosely coupled way. Please refer to [this blog post](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) for more information about this.

Comment: check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for my late reply. Thanks for your advice and example. I solved my problem with the following code. Iam using Prism library with IEventAggregator

My service

```
internal sealed class ApplicationService
{
    private ApplicationService() { }

    private static readonly ApplicationService _instance = new ApplicationService();

    internal static ApplicationService Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private Prisms.IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    internal Prisms.IEventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get
        {
            if (_eventAggregator == null)
            {
                _eventAggregator = new Prisms.EventAggregator();
            }


            return _eventAggregator;
        }
    }
```

then my first ViewModel which will publish the SelectAirport

```
public class AirportViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;


    public AirportViewModel(IEventAggregator EventAggregator)
    {
        //Liste des aéroports a suivre           
        Airports = new ObservableCollection<AirportModel>(GetData.GetAirportData());

        //Clique sur un aéroport
        GetAirportIdCommand = new RelayCommand(GetAirportIdExecute,GetAirportIdCanExeucte);

        #region Telechargement météo

        GetAllWeather GetAllWeather = new GetAllWeather(Airports);

        #endregion


        this.eventAggregator = EventAggregator;

    }
 //Property SelectAirport
    public AirportModel SelectAirport
    {
        get { return selectAirport; }
        set
        {
           selectAirport = value;
          //Publish the property SelectAirport 
          eventAggregator.GetEvent<AirportSelectedEvent> ().Publish(selectAirport);
          OnPropertyChanged("SelectAirport");

        }
    }
}
```

then my second ViewModel which will receive the SelectAirport

```
public class NotamViewModel  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public NotamViewModel(IEventAggregator ea)
    {
        _eventAggregator = ea;

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AirportSelectedEvent>()
         .Subscribe((_selectAirport) =>
         {
          this.SelectAirport = _selectAirport;


         });
    }
}
```

And finally my AirportSelectedEvent

```
public class AirportSelectedEvent : PubSubEvent<AirportModel>
{
}
```

I hope it can help you if needed.

See you soon for a lot of other question in WPF

Cyrille